# storing image file to MiFare classic 4K

Tags: android, nfc, rfid, mifare, ndef

i'm writing NDEF data  with a MIME type of text/plain to a MiFare classic 4k NFC tag , i also have to store a jpg (or any other possible format)in the NFC tag,i'm wondering how this could be done.

Comment: What do you try ? please share your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While anything is possible, saving a reference/link to an image is the preferred solution.

In general, I'd advice to minimize the amount of data stored on the tag. This will reduce read/write times and thus user errors.

Many tag types can not hold 4k of data, so you are basically locking into an obsolete (mifare classic) tag type which has decreasing chipset support in Android devices.

Comment: in the end ,i switched to use Mifare desFire ev1 4k and i managed to reduce the size of image to nearly 3k and stored it as base64 format .

Comment: Interesting, what kind of image was this really?

Comment: @joghm can you please elaborate how you managed to store the base64 format image to the Mifare card. I am using Mifare classic 4k card and trying to figure out a way to store image in the card.